"ORA-12541: TNS:no listener" but there are log entries in the listener log
I am using SQLPlus on a remote machine and after I put in my username and password it says "ORA-12541: TNS:no listener", but when I look at the listener log on the Oracle 19c server, there is an entry showing the connection.  What am I doing wrong?
I was trying to log in to SQLPlus when I got the error.
Here are my test results:

TNSPing Server Test Results:
Attempting to contact (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.100.132.16)(PORT = 1521))
OK (30 msec)

Yes, I can connect to sqlplus on the server

lsnrctl status listener
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "RADB" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "RADB", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

TNSPing Client Test Results: Message 3513 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSMessage 3509 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS

Telnet OK



Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It seems you are with wrong configuration environment variables, and my guess is you are trying to connect from a windows machine as client, correct?
Does the ORACLE_HOME was set at the System / Environment level on the Windows client? Do you have more than one Oracle Client installed?
You can try going to the Oracle Home Client bin folder, unset the ORACLE_HOME env (if is it set).
Test in a CMD prompt session like:
E:>\oracle\product\12.1\client_1\bin>set ORACLE_HOME=
Now try to TNSPing again.  The "no message file" errors should clear.
Is it the TNS_ADMIN env set? If not, you can try to set it to the correct ORACLE_HOME\network\admin folder, with the correct tnsnames.ora configured to your database.
Are you trying to connect with a user common account or using the sys as sysdba?
